# Processing Unstructured Big XML Files

Tags: xml, hadoop, xml-parsing, hive, apache-pig

I did following solution for XML files of size nearly 500 lines:

1. Converted big XML files into smaller XML with required elements files using XSLT
   tansformations
2. Than using SAXON XML parser in java code I did parsing of these new generated files
3. Than using concept of JAXB I unmarshlled XML to java objects and than to SQL SERVER.

but now I have new XML files which are very big nearly 15000 or more lines and are very unstructured. So using above solution to get data in database will be very inefficient. I am trying to figure out what could be best possible solution to work with with these large files. I did some research and came across this tool called as "Altova XML spy" with which I can make my unstructured XML files less complex.I tried to play with a single big file using this tool it did not worked well. Also I thought to dump these big files in hadoop cluster and use Hive/Pig to get data.

So my question is can anyone suggest any new solution or procedure. Any tool with which I can make big XML files into a bit less complex files to play with.

Hope this much information will be sufficient. Let me know if anything else needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to advise without understanding the problem in a lot more detail. The process you describe looks intrinsically very inefficient - I can't see why the JAXP step is needed - but perhaps there's a good reason for it. Sorry, but this isn't a simple coding question - it's one that needs a day or two of consultancy help.

Comment: Yes I agree to that but I cannot post everything on this forum so I thought with this much details someone will be able to post or suggest some direction to work with. Anyways I am thinking to do using HIVE. I am planning to dump everything in hadoop clusters and use HIVE/PIG to create queries. If anyone have suggestion about this that will be great help or someone can point me to some relevant resource. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on querying it with Pig anyway, how about using Pig to load it too?

For example `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader()` is a function to do this.

But if you think you need a cluster to play with 15,000 items, you are wrong. Any personal computer can manage 15,000 items. I agree here with Michael Kay, it is a very very small amount of data.

From the little experience I have with Hadoop clusters, if your query is faster than 30-40 seconds with a computer, there is no use for a cluster, because it will take about 30 seconds to set up the map-reduce job structure. And even for queries that take a few minutes on a personal computer, the complexity of a cluster is not worth the few seconds you will spare.

Comment: Comment: how do you manage to have _very unstructured_ XML-files? Isn't XML some kind of very structured way of storing data?

Comment: XML file is for storing data in structured format but files which I have are unstructured which is the reason why I am trying to figure out some way to get data from these files. As far as use of hadoop so though size of single file is not that big according to you guys but overall number of such files will be in millions and will increase with time. So keeping that part in mind I am trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: So what do you mean with "unstructured"? Those files do follow the XML structure, do they not? By this I mean that your data in including within the range of tags as in `<tagA>this is my data for tagA</tagA>`. If so, then they are structured, else you probably cannot call your file "XML-files". Also, if you have millions of files, then go for a cluster, I would recommend Hadoop but there are many more technologies out there. Pig connects of course very well with Hadoop File System (HDFS).

Comment: By unstructured I meant that few XML files has a particular hierarchy structure, few have a flat structure all elements present directly under root, different file may have different elements, different patterns within the data and so on. Hope this helps. Also I know that I can take Hadoop approach but can anyone tell me the few starting steps or the way the solution should proceed. Like what configuration hardware I should use for the cluster making and so on. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the test version of Cloudera CDH4 with VMware (it runs on any system), see if it could be something for you, if it is, then hire a database engineer. For further technical questions about the administration of the database, please refer to the specialized Q&A http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1500 lines doesn't sound very big to me. In fact, I would call it tiny.

Sorry I can't really help. I can't see why processing data of this sort of size should be a problem.

Comment: 15000 or more actually. Sorry that was a typo

Comment: @user1188611 if so, please update your question using 'edit'.

Comment: done editing but can someone provide with some ideas or suggestion.